# TFPT unshelve & Migrate: What is the Base version for merging?

Tags: merge, migrate, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to use tfpt unshelve /migrate to unshelve my shelveset on to a different branch.  When it does the unshelve, it also attempts to merge the file with the file in the target branch.  I do not understand where its getting the base version of this file.  Can anyone tell me what version is base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really found an answer to this, so i'm just left with my guess:

tfpt looks at the different versions of the file and constructs (in memory only) a 'base version' of the file.  In some cases, perhaps this works well, but for me it did not work at all.  I was unable to use it for merge and migrate.

Answer (score 1):

According to this post, it is a baseless merge:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2009/04/30/how-to-move-a-shelveset-to-another-branch.aspx